# Count Objects inside parent JSON Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

**JSON**

```
{
    "AA1 1AA":{
        "ExchangeCode":"XXX",
        "ExchangeName":"XXXXX",
        "Options":{
            "10":{
                "Preference":"Preference 1",
                "Option 1":123,
                "Option 2":1234,
                "Option 3":1234,
                "Option 4":1234
            },
            "20":{ .........

            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `AA1 1AA` is a postcode and so changes with every request.

**jQuery**

```
// var count = 0; is declared in document ready function so that it's global

// JSON response from server is stored in 'data'

 var key, count = 0;
 for (key in data.Options) {
     if(data.Options.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
         count++;
     }
 }
```

The result is just `undefined`

Comment: Aren't you skipping a level in your JSON? That is the first level is your *postcode*, once you have that you can then iterate through the *options*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want to get the first element. You may do this :

```
 var count = 0;
 for (var k in data) { // only simple cross browser way to get the first property
     var obj = data[k];
     for (var key in obj) {
         count++;
     }
     break; // no need to go further, we have counted in "AA1 1AA" 
 }
```

Note that I removed the `hasOwnProperty` check : it's totally useless for JSON parsed data.

Note that modern browsers have additional facilities, like [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Comment: I strongly disagreed with part about `hasOwnProperty`. Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9U7Yb/)

Comment: @Tommi You want me to precise : *"it's totally useless for JSON parsed data if you're not stupidely messing with Object's prototype"* ? Please **don't** abusively defend in your code, this makes verbose and slower code and you can't defend against stupidity. Add this kind of test only when necessary.

Comment: Yes. I want. Please take into account that you not always the only guy who write code in project, and also you can include code from somewhere else and you obviously can't maintain prototypes extending in this cases.

Comment: A code that extends Object's prototype is stupid (doing it with enumerable properties would be a special level in stupidity). Sometimes you deal with stupid, but you shouldn't add random protections in your code just in case somebody has this special kind of stupidity. Only add the protection when the need arises. Do you protect against the guy who overrides Array.prototype.push ? You can't and you shouldn't.

Comment: This is not the same case. If I'll detected that someone overrided it, I will protect, but Object extensions is much wider used, yes, it's bad, and yes, it's stupid, and yes, there are many warnings about it everywhere; but to say people that you should _not_ to check it just mean that we will see more questions about it on SO.

Comment: thanks, this seems to work for 3 iterations of the loop (there are 10 in the `Options` object) so not sure what's causing that.